# How to hide / make invisible formula in google spreadsheets

Tags: formula, cell, google-sheets-api

So i want to hide my formula at cells google spreadsheet. But anyone with the link can see the data (just cannot see the formula when they click the cell).

could i do it in google spreadsheets?

i don't hide my formula bar (i mean click view > show > formula bar, it isn't i want)

Answer (score 1):

### You can place your formula in a hidden column and create a [range protection](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en) for this column with the permisison that only you can edit this range

For example, if your secret formula is in column D:

- Mirror its content into column E with `=C1`
- Set a proteciton on column D
- Hide column D
- Other viewers and editors will only see the content of the other columns, but will not be able to unhide column D since they will have only a `view only` permission for the protected range:

[image]

---

---

[image]